# How to have a design instance of a viewmodel by deserialisation for a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl with a view model:

```
public partial class FarmLogPageView : UserControl
{
    public FarmLogPage? ViewModel
    {
        get => (FarmLogPage)DataContext;
        set => DataContext = value;
    }

    public FarmLogPageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dir = "D:\\_\\FolderQuantTests\\FarmLogPages\\";
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir);
        string json = File.ReadAllText(files.First());
        ViewModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FarmLogPage>(json);
    }
}
```

I also make sure I define the type of on the xaml side:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=diskManagerCore:FarmLogPage,
    IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
```

But my datacontext is empty (I should have something, according to the code behind constructor). I made sure have a parameterless constructor of the view model.

It's as if my code behind constructor was ignored.

How to have a design instance of the viewmodel based on serialized data from a file ?

PS this test passes (ie., I have correct class instance content):

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeserializeTest()
{
    var dir = "D:\\_\\FolderQuantTests\\FarmLogPages\\";
    var file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir).First(o => o.Contains("Drive"));
    Console.WriteLine($"using {file}");

    string json = File.ReadAllText(file);
    var sut = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FarmLogPage>(json);
    
    Assert.IsNotNull(sut);
    Assert.IsTrue(sut.ContentMap.Count > 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(28, sut.ContentMap.Count);
    //sut.ContentMap.ToCW();
}
```

Full View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DiskManagerUI.FarmLogPageView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DiskManagerUI"
             xmlns:diskManagerCore="clr-namespace:DiskManagerCore;assembly=DiskManagerCore"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=diskManagerCore:FarmLogPage, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Resources>

            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageType, FallbackValue=PageType}" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorRate, FallbackValue=errorrate}" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue=name}" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ContentMap}" BorderThickness="0" Background="AliceBlue">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using DiskManagerCore;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DiskManagerUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for FarmLogPageView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FarmLogPageView : UserControl
    {
        public FarmLogPage? ViewModel
        {
            get => (FarmLogPage)DataContext;
            set => DataContext = value;
        }

        public FarmLogPageView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var dir = "D:\\_\\FolderQuantTests\\FarmLogPages\\";
            var file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir).First(o => o.Contains("Drive"));
            string json = File.ReadAllText(file);
            ViewModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FarmLogPage>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
[Serializable]
public class FarmLogPage
{
    protected string[] Content { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FarmPageType PageType { get; set; }
    public bool HasContentMap { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> ContentMap { get; set; } = new();
    
    /// <summary>
    /// For tests or design
    /// </summary>
    public FarmLogPage()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the constructor to see whether the JsonSerializer returns an object? Set a breakpoint on the end-brace (`}`) of the  constructor and inspect `ViewModel`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The content is good, I updated the OP with more details.

Answer (score 1):

You should not deserialize files or traverse the file system from the constructor. This makes instantiation of the type a blocking operation. It's a code smell.

In addition, moving the code outside the constructor allows you to use the asynchronous `JsonSerializer` API (`JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync`), which will further improve the performance. Then better call the overload of `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` that allows to pass in a `Stream` (or the file path). Let the `JsonSerializer` handle the file to enable it to improve the performance. `File.ReadAllText` is not the best option. In general, prefer to use a `StreamReader` to read from a file as it allows asynchronous file access (e.g. `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync`).

```cs
public partial class FarmLogPageView : UserControl
{
    public FarmLogPage? ViewModel
    {
        get => (FarmLogPage)DataContext;
        set => DataContext = value;
    }

    public FarmLogPageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // You can also use the Loaded event if required.
    // Loaded event is raised after Initialized.
    protected override async void OnInitialized(EventArgs e) 
    {
      base.OnInitialized(e);

      var dir = "D:\\_\\FolderQuantTests\\FarmLogPages\\";
      var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir);
      string jsonFile = files.First();
      await using jsonFileStream = File.OpenRead(jsonFile);
      this.ViewModel = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<FarmLogPage>(jsonFileStream);
    }
}
```

Finally, to fix your issue you have to configure the design time data properly. You must set `IsDesignTimeCreatable` to `true`. Otherwise WPF will create a fake type and not instantiate the original type (hence your constructor is never invoked).
This fake type is only meant to provide the XAML designer an outline of the type so that Intellisense can make code suggestions.

```xml
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance diskManagerCore:FarmLogPage, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

---

After reviewing your code once more I realized that I had overlooked your design flaws that lead to your issues. I assumed a different (cleaner) design then you actually had.

The constructor of the controls that are displayed in the designer view is not called by design. In your current scenario the XAML engine creates an instance of `FarmLogPage` by invoking it's default constructor. But because the constructor of `FarmLogPageView` is bypassed when creating the design time data, you get an empty instance (only initialized with default values). At this point you could initialize the `FarmLogPage` with design time example data from the default constructor. But better don't do that. I wouldn't want to pollute my production classes with test or designer code.

You can fix your issue by improving your class design.
Because you named your property `ViewModel` I assume you are implementing the MVVM pattern. This pattern states that the View must not reference the Model or contain Model responsibilities.
Reading and writing data *is* Model business.

Adhering to the design MVVM rules you would have to move the file processing to the Model. Even if you don't implement MVVM you should follow the suggested design. The key is to hide the internals of `FarmLogPage` from `FarmLogPageView`. This allows `FarmLogPageView` to create instances simply by invoking the constructor. This will improve your overall class design as it cleans up the responsibilities.
The `FarmLogPageView` must not know where the data exactly comes from. Otherwise, it could store this data by itself. We have to move the responsibility to retrieve the data to the object that stores/handles it.

As a side-effect of the new class design, we can create a simple view model instance and defer the initialization, which enables the use of asynchronous code that we are not allowed to execute from the constructor.

Simply modify your class design as follows: don't let the control initialize the data context value via deserialization. Let the control tell the data context class to initialize itself e.g., by using deserialization. But those details should be hidden. The data context class will then call a Model class to get the data (from an unknown source - only the Model class knows the data source (JSON file) and how to deserialize the data).

Because in your case you deserialize a complete object, you must use composition and expose this data as a property of type `FarmLogPage`. In other words, you have to `wrap` FarmLogPage into a new type (e.g. `MainViewModel`):

**FarmLogPage.cs**

```cs
public class FarmLogPage
{
    protected string[] Content { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FarmPageType PageType { get; set; }
    public bool HasContentMap { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> ContentMap { get; set; } = new();
    
    /// <summary>
    /// For tests or design
    /// </summary>
    public FarmLogPage()
    {
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public FarmLogPage FarmLogPage { get; private set; }
  public bool IsInitialized { get; private set; }
  private DataProvider DataProvider { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.DataProvider = new DataProvider();
  }

  public async Task InitializeAsync()
  {
    if (this.IsInitialized)
    {
      return;
    }

    this.FarmLogPage = await this.DataProvider.GetFarmLogPageAsync();
    this.IsInitilaized = true;
  }
}
```

**DataProvider.cs**
The Model class.

```cs
class DataProvider
{
  public async Task<<FarmLogPage> GetFarmLogPageAsync()
  {
    var dir = "D:\\_\\FolderQuantTests\\FarmLogPages\\";
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir);
    string jsonFile = files.First();
    await using jsonFileStream = File.OpenRead(jsonFile);
    var dataModel = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<FarmLogPage>(jsonFileStream);

    return dataModel;
  }
}
```

**FarmLogPageView.cs**

```cs
partial class FarmLogPageView
{
  private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; }

  public FarmLogPageView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
  }

  // You can also use the Loaded event if required.
  // Loaded event is raised after Initialized.
  protected override async void OnInitialized(EventArgs e) 
  {
    base.OnInitialized(e);
  
    await this.MainViewModel.InitializeAsync();
    this.DataContext = this.MainViewModel.FarmLogPage;
  }
}
```

After fixing the design. You have to create a dedicated data context design data type. This is necessary because your data is required to be created at runtime. It's not done creating the `FarmLogPage` instance. The instance must be created by deserialization.
When you define

```xml
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance diskManagerCore:FarmLogPage, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

then the XAML engine does not know that the instance must be created via deserialization. It simply invokes the default constructor (resulting in an empty instance).

Even if the `FarmLogPageView` constructor had been called, the XAML designer would ignore the `FarmLogPage` instance created by deserialization. This instance is only available via the *runtime data context*. But you have instructed the designer to use the *design time data context*: two different instances, two different data contexts. One properly initialized and the other empty.

Now, to be able to specify a design time data object we must design a data type `FarmLogPageDesignData` that is by default initialized with design time example data:

**FarmLogPageDesignData.cs**

```cs
class FarmLogPageDesignData : FarmLogPage
{
  // Initialize with design data
  public FarmLogPageDesignData()
  {
    this.Name = ...;
    this.PageType = ...;
    this.HasContentMap = ...;
    puthis.ContentMap = ...;
  }
}
```

Then update the `DesignInstance`, so that the XAML engine can create a design time instance of `FarmLogPageDesignData`:

```xml
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance diskManagerCore:FarmLogPageDesignData, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

If you don't care to pollute your production type with design time data, you can avoid the `FarmLogPageDesignData` type and instead add the initialization with design time example data to the default constructor (I don't recommend this).

Another alternative is that you don't deserialize the complete instance. Instead read the initial data from the JSON and initialize the `FarmLogPage` with it.

Because of your special case where instantiation involves file operations, I would recommend implementing the dedicated design time data class (`FarmLogPageDesignData`).

Comment: With `IsDesignTimeCreatable=True` I have nothing, not even the fallback values; I thought it was unwanted because I understand that it overwrites the viewmodel instance from the ctor. Do you mean that I should have a DI instead of an instance created from the ctor ? I undertand the improvements, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: Yes, I know that the improvement suggestions don't solve the original problem. And I understand that you have not asked for any suggestions to improve your code. Maybe, you can just ignore them. The point is that `IsDesignTimeCreatable=False` is instructing the XAML designer to instantiate a fake instance. There will be no data, no constructor executed. But the designer is now able to provide designtime support when defining data bindings. If you define `IsDesignTimeCreatable=True` the XAML designer will create  a real instance of the specified type.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ff602277(v=vs.95)

Comment: You can also replace the DesignInstance attribute notation with ` <d:DesignerProperties.DataContext>
   <diskManagerCore:FarmLogPage />
 </d:DesignerProperties.DataContext>` in your XAML

Comment: Does the XAML designer give you any squiggles?

Comment: *"Do you mean that I should have a DI instead of an instance created from the ctor ?"* - No. I meant to separate type instantiation from initialization. In the constructor you are only supposed to initialize the instance with defaults. A constructor is not meant to be a longrunning operation or expensive resource allocations. For example, you create the view model instance from the control's constructor. Then in the Initialized or Loaded event you call the Initialize method on the view model (to be implemented). This way the Initialized can be defined as async. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I had reviewed your code once more and stumbled across your class design. The man "problem" is that the XAML designer will not invoke the constructor of the controls. In addition, DesignInstance will instruct the XAML engine to create a design time instance. Event if the control constructor had been called, the XAML designer would ignore the FarmLogPage created by deserialization. This instance is only available via the runtime data context. But the designer is using the design time data context: two different instances. One properly initialized and the other empty.

Comment: You can refer to my updated answer for a solution.